# Chat input wont clear when you post a chat message

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, chat

When you post a message in my chat the input box wont clear the message after it's sent. So you have to remove the last message every time.

My PHP:

```
fw::script_line('
    $(function(){
        function loop()
        {           
            Chat.cache('.$room['id'].');
            Log.cache('.$room['id'].');         
            Update.cache('.$room['id'].');  

            setTimeout(loop, 1000);             
        }

        loop();

        $(".input[name=content]").focus();

        $("#sidebar").hide();
    });
');
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="box chat">
    <div id="chat"></div>

    <form action="Javascript: Chat.post($('input[name=\'content\']').val());" method="get">
        <input type="text" class="input" name="content" placeholder="<?php echo lang('type_here'); ?>">

        <a class="a_button" onclick="Chat.post($('input[name=\'content\']').val());"><!-- Send !--></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set the value to "" in jquery. `$(".input").val("")`

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I set .val("") I can't post anything.
When I set .val('') It removes the message as I want but the output is [object Object]

Comment: you want to set the val to "" after you post it. Make sure you have already posted it before you clear it again. Can you put it in the onclick after your Chat.post?

Comment: Chat.post($('input[name=\'content\']').val(""));

This gives me [object Object] as output message. But it clears the input box as I want.

Comment: no after you post it then you want to set the val. In that case you are setting the value to "" and then pulling it...try doing `Chat.post($('input[name=\'content\']').val()); $('.input').val("")`